# How to make an item listview go to another activity when clicked instead of showing a toast?

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

I am using kotlin and I don't know how to implement the setonitemclicklistener to open another activity instead of showing a toast message.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener{parent, view, position, id ->

        if (position==0){
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Item One",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if (position==1){
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Item Two",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

Comment: maybe this helps: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you would just need to build an Intent with the Activity that you would like to launch, and launch it with the startActivity() method.

`startActivity(Intent(context, SecondActivity::class.java))`

Comment: if (position==0){
                val context
                startActivity(Intent(context, TimeForWork::class.java))
            }

Comment: the val context is giving me an error saying it needs a type annotation or be initialized. at first the app crashes when I click the position.

Comment: If you're already in an activity, you can replace context with the keyword this

Comment: Another question: I have a listview containing 40 items, do I need to make 40 activities? each list view activity is a story title when clicked I want to open an activity which contains the story (picture, audio file, text, adview) I Just want to make sure I am doing it right?

Comment: You'll probably want to make a data class that has all of the info (picture file, audio file, string, etc.) then pass that data class in the Intent using the putExtra(key, value) method of your intent. I highly recommend an intro to Android course to learn the basic Activity methods.

Comment: Thank you. I took some Android and Kotlin courses but I learn by doing and following examples. I am trying to get the story title, story body, story picture, story audio from string for each story but I do not know how to do it for the audio file and the picture. Is there a specific tutorial you recommend for this?

Answer (score 0):

You write your code like below

```
when(position){
            0 -> {
                var intent = Intent(applicationContext, FirstActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            1 -> {
                var intent = Intent(applicationContext, SecondActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
}
```